# How can I hide or disable a category in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I would like to disable a certain category on my WordPressblog. Lets call it Foo. So when a user tries to enter www.blog.com/Foo, they get redirected to my 404 page. How can I do this with htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's one way to do it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /Foo 404.html [R=404,L]
```

You could also change the slug for the Foo category to not be Foo anymore.

Comment: Thank you, i got it working with "Redirect /featured /404.php", but your sulotion looks better